# Cloudflare Zero Trust kubectl connection - private cluster

Tags: kubectl, cloudflare, cloudflare-argo

I'm following this article in order to secure `kubectl` connection with Cloudflare Zero Trust (using cloudflared daemon):
`https://developers.cloudflare.com/cloudflare-one/tutorials/kubectl/`

My cluster is private EKS cluster in private subnets. Now, how would you typically set this flow up. Would cloudflared be seated in worker nodes? Or should there be a bastion host in front of the cluster (with NAT gateway)?
Here (in the article) I can see `service` attribute. It seems to be pointing to kubernetes API. But what is the address inside the EKS? Is it what I see as `API server endpoint` in my EKS dashboard?

```
tunnel: 6ff42ae2-765d-4adf-8112-31c55c1551ef
credentials-file: /root/.cloudflared/6ff42ae2-765d-4adf-8112-31c55c1551ef.json

ingress:
  - hostname: azure.widgetcorp.tech
    service: tcp://kubernetes.docker.internal:6443
    originRequest:
      proxyType: socks
  - service: http_status:404
```

Many thanks for helping!